# Go from TEXT field to foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

product table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_name TEXT,
    nutriscore_grade TEXT,
    url TEXT,
    stores TEXT,
    purchase_places TEXT,
    pnns_groups_1 TEXT,
    pnns_groups_2 TEXT
);
```

and category table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
```

The product table is then populated with data like this:

```
mysql> select id, product_name, pnns_groups_2 from product limit 10;
+----+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| id | product_name                                       | pnns_groups_2                    |
+----+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Prince Chocolat                                    | Biscuits and cakes               |
|  2 | Cocacola Zero                                      | Artificially sweetened beverages |
|  3 | Nutella                                            | Sweets                           |
|  4 | Muesli Raisin, Figue, Abricot                      | Breakfast cereals                |
|  5 | Biscuit Sésame                                     | Biscuits and cakes               |
|  6 | Nutella biscuits                                   | Biscuits and cakes               |
|  7 | 100% mie complet                                   | Bread                            |
|  8 | Soupe 3 poissons aux algues                        | One-dish meals                   |
|  9 | Chocapic                                           | Breakfast cereals                |
| 10 | Nocciolata Pâte à tartiner au cacao et noisettes   | Sweets                           |
+----+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

and category table like this:

```
mysql> select * from category;
+----+--------------------+
| id | name               |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | Biscuits and cakes |
|  2 | Breads             |
|  3 | Breakfast cereals  |
|  4 | Sweets             |
|  5 | Cheese             |
+----+--------------------+
```

The goal here is to turn pnns_groups_2 field into a foreign key to reference the categories it matches.

Apparently, it's better practice because although I could just `SELECT * WHERE pnns_groups_2 = {my_category}`, it's better optimised if I use a foreign key instead, so I've been told.

However, I don't know how to proceed, I tried `ALTER TABLE product ADD CONSTRAINT fk_pnns_groups_2 FOREIGN KEY product(pnns_groups_2) REFERENCES category(id)`, but it seems like my fields are incompatible.

Then I tried to update to match category ID using `UPDATE product SET pnns_groups_2 = (SELECT id FROM category WHERE category.name = pnns_groups_2)`, and then `ALTER TABLE product MODIFY pnns_groups_2 INTEGER;` to match the data type, but all my values are `NULL` doing this.

I'm pretty beginner in SQL stuff, any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The foreign key should be the primary key in the referenced table.  I strongly recommend that you also use a name that is meaningful.  So, I would that the first table be:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        category_id INTEGER,
        product_name TEXT,
        nutriscore_grade TEXT,
        url TEXT,
        stores TEXT,
        purchase_places TEXT,
        pnns_groups_1 TEXT,
        FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (ID)
    );
```

You would then filter on a particular category either using the `id` or using a `JOIN` to match the category to the product.